# Laravel,Can I use auth('api')->user() in Middleware?

Tags: laravel, middleware, laravel-5.8

I Would like to use `auth('api')->user()` in Middleware ,But felt that it wouldn't work.
And I don't use `Auth::check()` Because it Return `null`

P.S. `auth('api')->user()` Can use in my Controller.

-This code check online/offline user-

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class LastUserActivity
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = auth('api')->user(); 
        if (isset($user)) {
            $expiresAt = Carbon::now()->addMinutes(1);
        Cache::put('user-is-online-' . $user->ID, true, $expiresAt);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: try: the Auth facade `Auth::guard('api')->user()` instead of `auth('api')->user()`

Comment: @loic.lopez work!!,thank you vary much. :D

Comment: You can also use the database session driver, and the session record will have a column `last_activity`. Or add a `last_active_at` column to the user table. Putting this value in a cache will bring only issues.